# Any negative consequences of linking from a wordpress site to another site that uses ASP pages

Tags: seo, wordpress, linux, windows, negative-seo

A client of mine had a blog that utilized ASP pages for some content.  Recently they moved their site to a Linux-based server and installed Wordpress.  They did not want to have all the ASP pages rewritten in PHP, so instead they are linking to a separate website for some pages.

My question is this, does this have any negative impacts on the main Wordpress website?  My primary concern is SEO but if any other concerns come to mind I'm all ears.

Comment: Did your client split his site into two of them because he didn't wanted to migrate content from ASP pages to Wordpress?

Comment: Correct.  He has dozens of ASP pages to perform certain functions and doesn't know PHP so he cannot use the same linux server for hosting the ASP pages.  eg: www.example.com would be the main site on the linux server and www.example2.com would be the site that the ASP pages are on.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no negative SEO consequences that can arise from this.

Answer (score 1):

If you split your content you could hurt your site rankings if you take away your ranked pages. If you take away non ranked pages, then it'll not impact your site. So check out which of your pages are ranking good, check which of them have external links, and keep them in your main site.

Maintaining two sites will be more work, and they will immediately compete against each other if they are about the same topics. It will be better to maintain just one, because it will be more robust than two in terms of content and authority.

The more recommendations (external links from good/authoritative sites) a website has, the more authoritative it becomes in one or many topics. The more valuable content a site has, the more recommendations (links) it may gain.